# How to email only exceptions using monolog (symfony2)

Tags: php, symfony, logging, guzzle, monolog

I am using `Monolog` in a `Symfony2` and now it's configured in this way:

```
 services:
          monolog.formatter.html:
          class: Monolog\Formatter\HtmlFormatter
monolog:
      handlers:
        main:
           type:         fingers_crossed
           action_level: critical
           handler:      swift
           handler:      grouped
       grouped:
           type:    group
           members: [streamed, buffered]
      streamed:
          type:  stream
          path:  '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'
          level: debug
      buffered:
          type:    buffer
          handler: swift
      swift:
          type:       swift_mailer
          from_email: 'email@gmail.com'
          to_email:   'email@gmail.com'
          subject:    An Error Occurred!
          level:      debug
          content_type: text/html
          formatter: monolog.formatter.html
```

And now it send me information about all events on my site. How can I configure it, to receive only messages about exceptions?

Additionly, most exceptions that i should catch and email came from guzzle library. Something like ( Client error response )

Comment: Why do you have 2 handler entries in your `main` section? I think with that configuration it sends you the whole log in case there was critical entry and nothing in other cases. If you want to have less info, try switching `level` to info/notice/warning/error in `swift` section.

Comment: i tried to set in this way (using warning or error levels in swift), but in this case it is not sent me anything in case of exception